# How do I play an automated call to a number in android?

Tags: android

The text to speech API in android is awesome.. Is there any way in which I can play this text to speech content to a call instead of the speaker? As in I call a number automatically and then play text to speech to the callee..

PS: This is not another opening to phone spam if you are wondering.. Working on an automated distress call system :D

Answer (score 2):

No. I don't believe there is. The closest thing you can do, is have the call set to speaker-phone and then play the voice over the speaker.

If would be a great option if Android could play sounds straight to the mic in a phone call. Many apps would benifit from this option, but it's just not possible yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..Talked to a few members of the android team, they said theres no api access to call streams both ways :( sad